# My AlertDialog with image view has no message?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to create  AlertDialog messages that appear one after another. I have image views that display information. However, I want to add a message as well. Although, I am setting a message it does not appear when the dialog is shown. Any ideas why my message does not appear? 
[image]

my class that deals with the alert dialog logic:

```
public class WhatsNewDialogCreator {
AlertDialog.Builder mBuilder;
AlertDialog mDialog;

public WhatsNewDialogCreator(final Context context) {
    ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.swipe_left);


    mBuilder =
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context).
    setMessage("Swipe left/right to change screens").
    setPositiveButton("Next", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            ImageView image2 = new ImageView(context);
            image2.setImageResource(R.drawable.swipe_refresh);
            AlertDialog.Builder builder =
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(context).
                            setMessage("Swipe down to refresh...").
                            setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            }).
                            setView(image2);
            builder.create().show();
        }
    }).
            setView(image)
            .setNeutralButton("Done", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                    mDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    mDialog = mBuilder.create();
}

public void show(){
    mDialog.show();
}
}
```

Comment: Because, your image view (**setView(image)**) replace dialog message. So, you can try with setTitle or use custom layout (**setView (your layout)**)

Comment: @DanhDC Thanks, I created layouts for both images and that work out just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You call

```
.setMessage("Swipe left/right to change screens")
```

which sets text for you on `AlertDialog`.

Then you call

```
.setView(image)
```

which is static image (content), which replaces already added text with this image.

You need to inflate layout, set for that layout your `ImageView` and `TextView` and set it as content.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I created 2 layouts (how DanhDC suggested) and set the in instead of the images and that worked out fine.

Comment: @GeorgiKoemdzhie I'm glad your problem is solved. If my answer explained you the problem and you don't need other help in this situation, you can mark it as accepted.